# Rails 4 Jquery-File-Upload cannot upload twice

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload, amazon-s3, jquery-file-upload

I am uploading pictures in a Rails 4 app directly to AWS s3 with jquery-file-upload following this article https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails

My goal is to upload 2 different versions of the same file from a single form: large and thumbnail.

The code for the upload is the following. The upload works fine and in the done callback I would like to start the second upload.

```
 fileInput.fileupload({
        fileInput:       fileInput,
        url:             form.data('url'),
        type:            'POST',
        autoUpload:       true,
        formData:         form.data('form-data'),
        paramName:        'file', // S3 does not like nested name fields i.e. name="user[avatar_url]"
        dataType:         'XML',  // S3 returns XML if success_action_status is set to 201
        replaceFileInput: false,
        disableImageResize: false,
        imageMaxWidth: 800,
        imageMaxHeight: 800,
        imageCrop: true,

        done: function(e, data) {
          console.log('DONE');

          // HERE I WOULD LIKE TO MAKE A SECOND UPLOAD
          startThumbnailUpload();
        },
      });
```

The code for the second upload is exactly the same except for the size and the url, but somehow the second fileInput.fileupload() never gets executed.

```
function startThumbnailUpload(){
  fileInput.fileupload({
    fileInput:       fileInput,
    url:             form.data('url'),
    type:            'POST',
    autoUpload:       true,
    formData:         form.data('form-data'),
    paramName:        'file', // S3 does not like nested name fields i.e. name="user[avatar_url]"
    dataType:         'XML',  // S3 returns XML if success_action_status is set to 201
    replaceFileInput: false,
    disableImageResize: false,
    imageMaxWidth: 200,
    imageMaxHeight: 200,
    imageCrop: true,

    done: function(e, data) {
      console.log('DONE');
    },
 });
}
```

The few SO subjects I could find on the subject so far mention to make sure the option replaceFileInput: false is present, which is.

The form code is the following:

```
= f.file_field :image_url, multiple: true, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png'
```

Any idea why? Could there be another solution for that kind of double upload?

Comment: Have you considered using Paperclip to do this?

Comment: I would like to keep the client side direct upload functionality